# slidewall doesn't work

Tags: 16.04, python

I installed slidewall on Ubuntu 16.04 using ppa:fioan89/slidewall.

I also installed python-appindicator, python-notify, python-notify2, python-webkit. But slidewall doesn't work.

Here are the errors I received:

```
$ /opt/extras.ubuntu.com/slidewall/bin/slidewall
/opt/extras.ubuntu.com/slidewall/slidewall/__init__.py:23: PyGIWarning: Gtk was imported without specifying a version first. Use gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0') before import to ensure that the right version gets loaded.
  from gi.repository import Gtk # pylint: disable=E0611
/opt/extras.ubuntu.com/slidewall/slidewall_lib/Builder.py:20: PyGIWarning: AppIndicator3 was imported without specifying a version first. Use gi.require_version('AppIndicator3', '0.1') before import to ensure that the right version gets loaded.
  from gi.repository import AppIndicator3 as appindicator
/opt/extras.ubuntu.com/slidewall/slidewall_engine/NotifyEngine.py:16: PyGIWarning: Notify was imported without specifying a version first. Use gi.require_version('Notify', '0.7') before import to ensure that the right version gets loaded.
  from gi.repository import Notify
Please make sure you have installed python image module
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Did you install slidewall with these three commands? `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:noobslab/apps`
`sudo apt-get update`
`sudo apt-get install slidewall`

Comment: no, I install it from ppa:fioan89/slidewall

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had same problem but it got solved after I installed python-imaging: `sudo apt install python-imaging`